# IOS integrate php - Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 xcode 11

Tags: php, ios, cross-compiling

I'm trying to integrate php 7.3 library into my IOS project.

To cross-compile php for arm64 I've used this sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# NOTE: PHP thinks "finite" is available, but it's not. You have to disable it manually in the config.h file.

PLATFORM=iPhoneOS # iPhoneSimulator # iPhoneOS
HOST=arm-apple-darwin10 # i386-apple-darwin10 # arm-apple-darwin10
ARCH=arm64 # i386 # armv7s #armv7
SDK_VERSION=12.1

XCODE_ROOT=`xcode-select -print-path`
PLATFORM_PATH=$XCODE_ROOT/Platforms/$PLATFORM.platform/Developer
SDK_PATH=$PLATFORM_PATH/SDKs/$PLATFORM$SDK_VERSION.sdk
FLAGS="-isysroot $SDK_PATH -arch $ARCH -miphoneos-version-min=$SDK_VERSION" # -miphoneos-version-min=$SDK_VERSION -mios-simulator-version-min=$SDK_VERSION"
PLATFORM_BIN_PATH=$XCODE_ROOT/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
CC=$PLATFORM_BIN_PATH/clang
CXX=$PLATFORM_BIN_PATH/clang++
CFLAGS="$FLAGS -std=gnu99"
CXXFLAGS="$FLAGS -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++"
LDFLAGS=$FLAGS

export CC CXX CFLAGS CXXFLAGS LDFLAGS

CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--host=$HOST --enable-embed=static --without-pear --disable-opcache --without-iconv --disable-cgi --disable-shared --disable-cli --enable-mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysqli --with-mysql --with-tsrm-pthreads"
./configure $CONFIGURE_FLAGS
```

Then I've integrated libphp7.a file into "Linked frameworks and libraries" in xcode and tried to build the project. But I receive this error:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "___clear_cache", referenced from:
      _sljit_generate_code in libphp7.a(pcre2_jit_compile.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What am I doing wronk and how to integrate php correctly?